# What is the "OS" key

Tags: modifiers, objects

In a video on Precision Drawing Tools there is a reference to a OS+S operation. What is the OS key?

Comment: OS: Operating System. OS Key also known as Meta key generally the key with the Windows logo on it for PCs, on Mac I believe its the Command key with the clover symbol

Answer (score 3):

I assume that would be the "Windows" or "Apple" or "Super" key. Its name varies depending on your OS (Windows, Mac or Linux). It's the one between Ctrl and Alt on most keyboards.
I've never heard it be called "OS" key though, so I might be wrong. If so, I'm curious to know what it is.

Answer (score 1):

Windows and Mac Keyboard Differences

- <kbd>Mac</kbd> = <kbd>Windows</kbd>
- <kbd>Control</kbd>  = <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>
- <kbd>Option</kbd> = <kbd>Alt</kbd>
- <kbd>Command</kbd> (Cloverleaf) = <kbd>Windows</kbd>
- <kbd>Delete</kbd> = <kbd>Backspace</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

i think these,

depends of your system

[image]

or

[image]