# How do I Alt+Left Mouse on a MacBook Air?

Tags: modeling, materials, workflow, network, blenderkit

I have a mouse but I do not have alt on my mac.
On Blender

Comment: I'd say this is a Google search type of question that will be faster than waiting for a Blender stackexchange response.  And I for one don't know...

Comment: I believe the Mac Option key is equivalent to the Windows Alt key but not having a Mac I can't check. See the answer half way down [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/181550/what-is-the-os-key/181560#181560) page.

Answer (score 0):

When Windows people say Alt, use the Option key. When they say left-click, they just mean click. So alt-left click is Option-click.